# JQuery - modify attributes of multiple cloned elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I have asked a similar question, but have since made a lot of progress so I wanted to share it.

Basically, I have form elements which can be dragged and dropped - it makes use of clone.  It allows me to create my own forms.  The problem is, an output might be something like so

```
<form id="content">

  <div data-type="text" class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-5" for="text_input">Text Input</label>
    <div class="controls col-sm-7">
      <input type="text" name="text_input" class="form-control" id="text_input">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-type="text" class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-5" for="text_input">Text Input</label>
    <div class="controls col-sm-7">
      <input type="text" name="text_input" class="form-control" id="text_input">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-type="textarea" class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-5 control-label green" for="textareaInput">Text Area:</label>
    <div class="controls col-sm-7">
      <textarea cols="50" name="textareaInput" id="textareaInput" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-type="textarea" class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-5 control-label green" for="textareaInput">Text Area:</label>
    <div class="controls col-sm-7">
      <textarea cols="50" name="textareaInput" id="textareaInput" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-type="date" class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-5" for="dateInput">Date Input:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="text" name="dateInput" class="form-control date_picker" id="dateInput">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-type="date" class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-5" for="dateInput">Date Input:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="text" name="dateInput" class="form-control date_picker" id="dateInput">
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Save Template" id="templateSubmit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

The problem with this is that if I clone 2 form elements of the same type, they both have the same name and id like shown above.  So I need to make sure that each cloned element has a unique name and id.  At the moment, I have a partial solution.

I have created a fiddle here [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLgrfzaL/26/)  If you click Save Template, you will see what happens.  The id numbers seem very strange, for instance textareaInput222.  Really, each element type should start at 0, and 1 be added to it for each additional element of the same type.

Would this be possible?  The other thing I am struggling with is setting the elements labels for attribute to be the same as the name which is set for that element.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#content").find(".form-group").each(function() {

$("textarea").each(function(index, value) {
```

my friend, these two each is the reason. There are around 6 .form-group element, so that textarea#each ran 6 times. And regard to DRY, here I gave my version https://jsfiddle.net/yjaL2zgL/2/

Comment: Thanks, works perfect.  Is there any way to get the for attribute for the label the same as the inputs id?  Thanks

Comment: @kate_hudson Sure, you have already get the way to set :input element id. It's same for label, while updating input's id,  find label element ( e.g. jquery prev() method ) and update it's id.

Comment: I am trying alert($elem.closest('div').find('label').html()); within the loop, but it returns undefined

Comment: coz $elem.closest('div') is div.controls, which is siblings of label. Try $elem.closest('.form-group').find('label') @kate_hudson

Answer (score 1):

I'd use underscore.js's unique id function personally, or your own implementation of it and suffix every id with a unique number on the page that increments like "dateInput-345". Even just using a counter variable that everything uses would be easy enough instead of basing it on indexes in loops.

http://underscorejs.org/#uniqueId

your own counter:
instead of using

```
(index + 1)
```

you can use something like

```
var uid = 0; //this needs to be where you declared your other vars
```

then when you need an id:

```
var new_id = $(value).attr("id") + '-' + uid++;
```

just make sure you arent copying an id that already has a number attached to it or you need to deal with that too.

Comment: Thanks.  I am using a counter at the moment, but having difficulties with it